# Tomcat 8.5.5 throws org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, https

I am getting error while deploying tomcat 8.5.5 with ssL

14-Jul-2023 09:51:49.563 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:244)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.skipBytes(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:221)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.readSniExtension(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:240)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:121)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:169)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1387)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

14-Jul-2023 09:51:49.563 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:244)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.skipBytes(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:221)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.readSniExtension(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:240)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor.(TLSClientHelloExtractor.java:121)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:169)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1387)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

here is SSL configuration

```html
<Connector
             port="8443"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             SSLEnabled="true"
             scheme="https"
             secure="true"
             keystoreFile="/app/asdf/abcd.jks"
             keystorePass="abcd"
             clientAuth="false"
             sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```